# How to tell whether on sub-view's is above another sub-view?

Tags: iphone, uiview

Assume there are 3 sub-views (A, B, C) in a view. After a few rounds of random `bringSubviewToFront` and `sendSubviewToBack` on A, B, or C , how can I tell whether one sub-view (e.g. A) is on top of another sub-view (e.g. C)?

Whether they overlap each other is not required information.

Thanks!

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2343432/how-to-get-uiview-hierarchy-index-i-e-the-depth-in-between-the-other-subvie

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The order of subviews in a view is the same as the order in the subviews array.  Which ever subview has a higher index in the subviews array is on top.