# iphone: view index

Tags: iphone, ipad

I have a view between other views, the order may vary. For example: viewA on top of viewB, on top of viewC, or in another order.

Suppose I have

viewA, viewB, viewC, viewD and viewE

A is on the top and E on the bottom.

I need to replace viewC with viewZ, but I need to insert viewZ in the same index of viewC.

How do I know, before removing viewC, what index it has, so I can insert viewZ using

```
[self.view insertSubview:viewZ atIndex:?????)
```

and it will be at the same level?

thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [How to get UIView hierarchy index ??? (i.e. the depth in between the other subviews)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2343432/how-to-get-uiview-hierarchy-index-i-e-the-depth-in-between-the-other-subvie)

```
int index = [[superView subviews] indexOfObject:viewC];
```

Answer (score 1):

Besides getting the index, you could also use `-insertSubview:aboveSubview:` (and `…belowSubview:`):

```
UIView* superview = self.view;
[superview insertSubview:viewZ aboveSubview:viewC];
[viewC removeFromSuperview];
```