# How can I get the index of sub UIView in the parent view?

Tags: ios, uiview

I want to use **exchangeSubviewAtIndex:** withSubviewAtIndex: method.

but how can i get the indexes of those views? i already have their pointers, so I thought there might be a method like.

```
[parentView indexOfSubview:subview];
```

but I couldn't find that kind of thing in Xcode documents library.

please help me! thank you in advance.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2343432/how-to-get-uiview-hierarchy-index-i-e-the-depth-in-between-the-other-subvi check this

Answer (score 28):

This is how you get it:

`[parentView.subviews indexOfObject:subview];`

In Swift:

```
parentView.subviews.firstIndex(of: subview)
```

Answer (score 9):

You can find out the index of your object as you find in [NSArray](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSArray_Class/NSArray.html), because view.subviews return an array

```
NSUInteger index1=[parentView.subviews indexOfSubview:subview1];
NSUInteger index2=[parentView.subviews indexOfSubview:subview2];

[parentView exchangeSubviewAtIndex:index1 withSubviewAtIndex:index2];
```

You can follow this link for more [How to get UIView hierarchy index ??? (i.e. the depth in between the other subviews)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2343432/how-to-get-uiview-hierarchy-index-i-e-the-depth-in-between-the-other-subvi)

Comment: your code needs a bit of editing @Rajneesh...

NSUInteger index1=[parentView.subviews indexOfObject:subview1];
NSUInteger index2=[parentView.subviews indexOfObject:subview2];

[parentView exchangeSubviewAtIndex:index1 withSubviewAtIndex:index2];

You'll note the indexOfSubview changes to indexOfObject and exchangeObjectAtIndex changes to exchangeSubviewAtIndex on the parentView

Answer (score 3):

```
[View.subviews indexOfObject:SubView];
```

Answer (score 2):

You can get array index using this.

```
[view.subViews indexOfObject:yourSubView];
```

And try to catch that index.

```
NSInteger index=[view.subViews indexOfObject:yourSubView];
```

Try this code might be helpful to you...