# Xamarin - How to get the index of a Subview into a Superview

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios

I think I need a solution for [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17758891/how-can-i-get-the-index-of-sub-uiview-in-the-parent-view) , but using Xamarin.
I need to create a function like...

```
    private int getMyViewIndex(UIView v) { 

    }
```

Where I send an UIView as parameter and this will return me the index corresponding to Superview. Any suggestions ? tyvm !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried

```
var index = Array.IndexOf(MyView.Subviews, mySearchedView);
```