# Event handling for iOS - how hitTest:withEvent: and pointInside:withEvent: are related?

Tags: ios, uiview, uikit

While most apple documents are very well written, I think '[Event Handling Guide for iOS](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/EventHandling/Conceptual/EventHandlingiPhoneOS/Introduction/Introduction.html)' is an exception. It's hard for me to clearly understand what's been described there.

The document says,

> In hit-testing, a window calls `hitTest:withEvent:` on the top-most view of the view hierarchy; this method proceeds by recursively calling `pointInside:withEvent:` on each view in the view hierarchy that returns YES, proceeding down the hierarchy until it finds the subview within whose bounds the touch took place. That view becomes the hit-test view.

So is it like that only `hitTest:withEvent:` of the top-most view is called by the system, which calls `pointInside:withEvent:` of all of subviews, and if the return from a specific subview is YES, then calls `pointInside:withEvent:` of that subview's subclasses?

Comment: A very good tutorial that helped me out [link](http://smnh.me/hit-testing-in-ios)

Comment: The equivalent newer document for this might now be https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiview/1622469-hittest

Answer (score 179, accepted):

It seems quite a basic question. But I agree with you the document is not as clear as other documents, so here is my answer.

The implementation of `hitTest:withEvent:` in UIResponder does the following:

- It calls `pointInside:withEvent:` of `self`
- If the return is NO, `hitTest:withEvent:` returns `nil`. the end of the story.
- If the return is YES, it sends `hitTest:withEvent:` messages to its subviews.
  it starts from the top-level subview, and continues to other views until a subview
  returns a non-`nil` object, or all subviews receive the message.
- If a subview returns a non-`nil` object in the first time, the first `hitTest:withEvent:` returns that object. the end of the story.
- If no subview returns a non-`nil` object, the first `hitTest:withEvent:` returns `self`

This process repeats recursively, so normally the leaf view of the view hierarchy is returned eventually.

However, you might override `hitTest:withEvent` to do something differently. In many cases, overriding `pointInside:withEvent:` is simpler and still provides enough options to tweak event handling in your application.

Comment: Do you mean `hitTest:withEvent:` of all subviews are executed eventually?

Comment: Yes. Just override `hitTest:withEvent:` in your views (and `pointInside` if you want), print a log and call `[super hitTest...` to find out whose `hitTest:withEvent:` is called in which order.

Comment: shouldn't step 3 where you mention "If the return is YES, it sends hitTest:withEvent: ...shouldn't it be pointInside:withEvent?  I thought it sends pointInside to all subviews?

Comment: Back in February it first sent hitTest:withEvent:, in which a pointInside:withEvent: was sent to itself. I haven't re-checked this behavior with following SDK versions, but I think sending hitTest:withEvent: makes more sense because it provides a higher-level control of whether an event belongs to a view or not; pointInside:withEvent: tells whether the event location is on the view or not, not whether the event belongs to the view. For example, a subview may not want to handle an event even if its location is on the subview.

Comment: I think, it also be consider the zOrder of subviews. the enumeration subviews might be from top zOrder to lower. If two view belongs to the some parent view. The two views intersect each other. The one at to top will be first called.

Comment: WWDC2014 Session 235 - Advanced Scrollviews and Touch Handling Techniques gives great explanation and example for this problem.

Comment: What does "top level" subview mean in this case? Does it go through the `subviews` array from index 0, or from the other end?

Comment: It reverses the subview array and then sends in incrementing index order. i.e. logically equivalent to sending hittest: last index to fist index.

Comment: Ridiculously useful answer. I never would've guessed that `pointInside:withEvent` is **called by** `hitTest` on the same object. And this actually helped me resolve a massive issue today, thank you!

Answer (score 305):

I think you are confusing subclassing with the view hierarchy. What the doc says is as follows. Say you have this view hierarchy. By hierarchy I'm not talking about class hierarchy, but views within views hierarchy, as follows:

```
+----------------------------+
|A                           |
|+--------+   +------------+ |
||B       |   |C           | |
||        |   |+----------+| |
|+--------+   ||D         || |
|             |+----------+| |
|             +------------+ |
+----------------------------+
```

Say you put your finger inside `D`. Here's what will happen:

1. `hitTest:withEvent:` is called on `A`, the top-most view of the view hierarchy.
2. `pointInside:withEvent:` is called recursively on each view.

   1. `pointInside:withEvent:` is called on `A`, and returns `YES`
   2. `pointInside:withEvent:` is called on `B`, and returns `NO`
   3. `pointInside:withEvent:` is called on `C`, and returns `YES`
   4. `pointInside:withEvent:` is called on `D`, and returns `YES`
3. On the views that returned `YES`, it will look down on the hierarchy to see the subview where the touch took place. In this case, from `A`, `C` and `D`, it will be `D`.
4. `D` will be the hit-test view

Comment: Thank you for the answer. What you described is also what was in my mind, but @MHC says `hitTest:withEvent:` of B, C and D are also invoked. What happens if D is a subview of C, not A? I think I got confused...

Comment: In my drawing, D is a subview of C.

Comment: Wouldn't `A` return `YES` as well, just as `C` and `D` does?

Comment: Don't forget that views that are invisible (either by .hidden or opacity below 0.1), or have user interaction turned off will never respond to hitTest. I don't think hitTest is being called on these objects in the first place.

Comment: Just wanted to add that hitTest:withEvent: may be called on all the views depending on their hierarchy.

Comment: I want to say that, you are wrong. If you define a custom subclass of uiview, you'll notice that no one calls your pointInside. the `hitTest` is the only method that is called by your parent view. and in your implementation of hitTest, you don't call subview's pointInside, you just call hitTest.

Answer (score 52):

I find this [Hit-Testing in iOS](http://smnh.me/hit-testing-in-ios/) to be very helpful

[image]

```
- (UIView *)hitTest:(CGPoint)point withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    if (!self.isUserInteractionEnabled || self.isHidden || self.alpha <= 0.01) {
        return nil;
    }
    if ([self pointInside:point withEvent:event]) {
        for (UIView *subview in [self.subviews reverseObjectEnumerator]) {
            CGPoint convertedPoint = [subview convertPoint:point fromView:self];
            UIView *hitTestView = [subview hitTest:convertedPoint withEvent:event];
            if (hitTestView) {
                return hitTestView;
            }
        }
        return self;
    }
    return nil;
}
```

**Edit Swift 4:**

```
override func hitTest(_ point: CGPoint, with event: UIEvent?) -> UIView? {
    if self.point(inside: point, with: event) {
        return super.hitTest(point, with: event)
    }
    guard isUserInteractionEnabled, !isHidden, alpha > 0 else {
        return nil
    }

    for subview in subviews.reversed() {
        let convertedPoint = subview.convert(point, from: self)
        if let hitView = subview.hitTest(convertedPoint, with: event) {
            return hitView
        }
    }
    return nil
}
```

Comment: So you need to add this to a subclass of UIView and have all the views in your hierarchy inherit from it?

Answer (score 21):

Thanks for answers, they helped me to solve situation with "overlay" views.

```
+----------------------------+
|A +--------+                |
|  |B  +------------------+  |
|  |   |C            X    |  |
|  |   +------------------+  |
|  |        |                |
|  +--------+                | 
|                            |
+----------------------------+
```

Assume `X` - user's touch. `pointInside:withEvent:` on `B` returns `NO`, so `hitTest:withEvent:` returns `A`. I wrote category on `UIView` to handle issue when you need to receive touch on top most *visible* view.

```
- (UIView *)overlapHitTest:(CGPoint)point withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    // 1
    if (!self.userInteractionEnabled || [self isHidden] || self.alpha == 0)
        return nil;

    // 2
    UIView *hitView = self;
    if (![self pointInside:point withEvent:event]) {
        if (self.clipsToBounds) return nil;
        else hitView = nil;
    }

    // 3
    for (UIView *subview in [self.subviewsreverseObjectEnumerator]) {
        CGPoint insideSubview = [self convertPoint:point toView:subview];
        UIView *sview = [subview overlapHitTest:insideSubview withEvent:event];
        if (sview) return sview;
    }

    // 4
    return hitView;
}
```

1. We should not send touch events for hidden or transparent views, or views with `userInteractionEnabled` set to `NO`;
2. If touch is inside `self`, `self` will be considered as potential result.
3. Check recursively all subviews for hit. If any, return it.
4. Else return self or nil depending on result from step 2.

Note, `[self.subviewsreverseObjectEnumerator]` needed to follow view hierarchy from top most to bottom. And check for `clipsToBounds` to ensure not to test masked subviews.

Usage:

1. Import category in your subclassed view.
2. Replace `hitTest:withEvent:` with this

```or-tag-here
- (UIView *)hitTest:(CGPoint)point withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    return [self overlapHitTest:point withEvent:event];
}
```

[Official Apple's Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/EventHandling/Conceptual/EventHandlingiPhoneOS/event_delivery_responder_chain/event_delivery_responder_chain.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009541-CH4-SW2) provides some good illustrations too.

Hope this helps somebody.

Comment: Amazing!  Thanks for the clear logic and GREAT code snippet, solved my head-scratcher!

Comment: @Lion, Nice answer. Also you can check equality to clear color in first step.

Answer (score 5):

**iOS Touch Event**

```
1. user made a touch
2. system creates an event object with global coordinate of touch
3. hit testing by coordinate - find First Responder

4.1 send Touch Event to `UIGestureRecognizer`. After handling the touch can or can not(depends on setup) be forward to the First Responder

4.2 send Touch Event to the First Responder
4.2.1 handle Touch Event
```

**Class diagram**

[image]

**3 Hit Testing**

Hit Testing to find a First Responder - checking hierarchy of UIView and successors of it (e.g. UIWindow). Recursively find a front view starting from the biggests(back) UIView(UIWindow is a start/root point) to the smallest(front)) UIView. As a result `First Responder` in this case is a top (the smallest) `UIView`, `point()` method(`hitTest()` uses `point()` internally) of which returned `true`.

```
func hitTest(_ point: CGPoint, with event: UIEvent?) -> UIView?
func point(inside point: CGPoint, with event: UIEvent?) -> Bool
```

Internally `hitTest()` takes into account

- `point() == true`
- `point()` takes into account rectangle which is inside superview
- `isUserInteractionEnabled == true`
- `isHidden == false`

```
func hitTest() -> View? {
    if (isUserInteractionEnabled == false || isHidden == true || alpha == 0 || point() == false) { return nil }

    for subview in subviews {
        if subview.hitTest() != nil {
            return subview
        }
    }
    return nil
}
```

Notes:

- by default when you set `view.isUserInteractionEnabled = false` this view and all it's subview will not handle the touch event
- by default `point()` takes into account rectangle which lay into superview. It means that if a touch is occured on a view part which is drawn out of superview, this view and all it's subview will not handle the touch event

[[UIView.clipsToBounds]](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73513083/4770877)

**4 Send UIEvent**

`UIKit` creates `UIEvent` which is sent by `UIApplication.shared.sendEvent()` to `main event loop`[<sup>[About]</sup>](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75204210/4770877). `UIEvent contains one or more` UITouch`which contains -`UIView`, location...

It always go through `UIApplication.sendEvent() -> UIWindow.sendEvent() -> <First_Responder>`

```
UIApplication.sendEvent() -> UIWindow.sendEvent() -> <First_Responder>.touchesBegan()
UIApplication.sendEvent() -> UIWindow.sendEvent() -> <First_Responder>.touchesEnded()
```

```
//UIApplication.shared.sendEvent()

//UIApplication, UIWindow
func sendEvent(_ event: UIEvent)
```

**4.1 send Touch Event to `UIGestureRecognizer`**

It is a simple and handy way to work with gestures. There are some out of box `UIGestureRecognizer` like `UITapGestureRecognizer`, `UISwipeGestureRecognizer` ... and you are able to create your own

```
let tap_v_0_2 = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(self.onView_0_2))
view_0_2.addGestureRecognizer(tap_v_0_2)

@objc func onView_0_2() {
    print("---> onView V_0_2")
}
```

System tries to find a `UIGestureRecognizer` in a view hierarchy. Starts from first responder (using `UIView.superview`) up to`UIWindow`(subclass of `UIView`). It means if you setup `UIGestureRecognizer` on `UIWindow` and first responder is `UIView_0` without `UIGestureRecognizer` - `UIWindow.UIGestureRecognizer` will be called

There are some functions to hadle work between `UIGestureRecognizer` in `UIGestureRecognizerDelegate`

And some functions to handle forwarding event to Responder Chain like: `cancelsTouchesInView`, `delaysTouchesBegan`, `delaysTouchesEnded`

**4.2 Send Touch Event to the `First Responder`**

It is more low level and more advanced approach where you can customize your logic. To use it you should **inherit** from `UIView` and override some methods, like:

```
//UIResponder
func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?)
func touchesMoved(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?)
func touchesEnded(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?)
func touchesCancelled(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?)
```

When UIView_0_2 is a first responder:

[image]

**4.2.1 Handle Touch Event**

When FirstRessponder is found it's a time to handle Touch Event using `Responder Chain`

**Responder Chain**

It a kind of `chain of responsibility` pattern who extends `UIResponder`. Every `UIResponder` has `next` property which points on next responder in the chain

By default:

- `UIView.next` -> superview ?? `UIViewController`
- `UIViewController.next` -> `UINavigationController` ?? `UIWindow`
- `UIWindow.next` -> `UIApplication`

Abstract diagram:
[image]

Print responder chain starting from UIView_0_2:

```
UIView_0_2 -> UIView_0 -> ViewController -> UIDropShadowView -> UITransitionView -> CustomWindow -> UIWindowScene -> CustomApplication -> AppDelegate
```

In case with Touch Event:

- it starts from FirstResponder and try to find overrode appropriate method (e.g. `touchesBegan()`...) If this method was not overrode - `UIResponder.next` is used to find next responder and try to call this method there
- if you call `super.touchesBegan()` inside `override func touchesBegan()` - `UIResponder.next` is used to find next responder and try to call this method there

For example if first responder is UIView_0_2 but touchesBegan() is override in UIWindow(not in UIView_0_2) - UIWindow will hadle this touch event

```
UIWindow hitTest BEGIN
UIWindow point result:true
    UIView_0 hitTest BEGIN
    UIView_0 point result:true
      UIView_0_1 hitTest BEGIN
      UIView_0_1 point result:false
      UIView_0_1 hitTest END result: nil

      UIView_0_2 hitTest BEGIN
      UIView_0_2 point result:true
        UIView_0_2_1 hitTest BEGIN
        UIView_0_2_1 hitTest END result: nil
      UIView_0_2 hitTest END result: UIView_0_2
    UIView_0 hitTest END result: UIView_0_2
UIWindow hitTest END result: UIView_0_2
```

Let's take a look at example:

[image] [image]

**Additional usage of Responder Chain**

`Responder chain` is also used by `UIControl.addTarget()` or `UIApplication.sendAction()` approaches like event bus.

```
customButton.addTarget(nil, action: #selector(CustomApplication.onButton), for: .touchUpInside)
//target is nil. In other cases Responder Chain is not ussed

UIApplication.shared.sendAction(#selector(CustomApplication.foo), to: nil, from: self, for: nil)
```

Internally it uses `UIResponder.target()` and `UIResponder.canPerformAction()`. When first UIRessponder starts a flow - `target()` is called, if `super.target()` is called inside `override func target()` then `canPerformAction()` is called, if `canPerformAction()` returns false then `next` is used to find a next UIResponder and recursively repeated these steps, if `canPerformAction()` returns true(by default the selector was found in this object) then this target will be recursively returned back and will be used to call the selector

Notes:

- When target doesn't contain a selector but `canPerformAction()` returns true next error is thrown:

> unrecognized selector sent to instance

For example - you call `UIApplication.shared.sendAction(#selector(CustomApplication.foo), to: nil, from: self, for: nil)` from `UIViewController` and(as you can see) `foo` selector is located in `CustomApplication`(`UIApplication`)

```
    UIViewController target Begin
    UIViewController canPerformAction result:false
    UIViewController next is: UIWindow
  UIWindow target Begin
  UIWindow canPerformAction result:false
  UIWindow next is UIApplication
UIApplication target begin
UIApplication canPerformAction result:true
UIApplication target result: UIApplication
  UIWindow target result: UIApplication
    UIViewController target result: UIApplication
//foo method body logic
```

[[Android onTouch]](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57222691/4770877)

Answer (score 4):

It shows like this snippet!

```
- (UIView *)hitTest:(CGPoint)point withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    if (self.hidden || !self.userInteractionEnabled || self.alpha < 0.01)
    {
        return nil;
    }

    if (![self pointInside:point withEvent:event])
    {
        return nil;
    }

    __block UIView *hitView = self;

    [self.subViews enumerateObjectsWithOptions:NSEnumerationReverse usingBlock:^(id obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {   

        CGPoint thePoint = [self convertPoint:point toView:obj];

        UIView *theSubHitView = [obj hitTest:thePoint withEvent:event];

        if (theSubHitView != nil)
        {
            hitView = theSubHitView;

            *stop = YES;
        }

    }];

    return hitView;
}
```

Comment: I find this the easiest to understand answer, and it matches my observations of the actual behaviour very closely. The only difference is that the subviews are enumerated in reverse order, so subviews closer to the front receive touches in preference to siblings behind them.

Comment: @DouglasHill thanks to your correction. Best regards

Answer (score 1):

The snippet of @lion works like a charm. I ported it to swift 2.1 and used it as an extension to UIView. I'm posting it here in case somebody needs it.

```
extension UIView {
    func overlapHitTest(point: CGPoint, withEvent event: UIEvent?) -> UIView? {
        // 1
        if !self.userInteractionEnabled || self.hidden || self.alpha == 0 {
            return nil
        }
        //2
        var hitView: UIView? = self
        if !self.pointInside(point, withEvent: event) {
            if self.clipsToBounds {
                return nil
            } else {
                hitView = nil
            }
        }
        //3
        for subview in self.subviews.reverse() {
            let insideSubview = self.convertPoint(point, toView: subview)
            if let sview = subview.overlapHitTest(insideSubview, withEvent: event) {
                return sview
            }
        }
        return hitView
    }
}
```

To use it, just override *hitTest:point:withEvent* in your uiview as follows:

```
override func hitTest(point: CGPoint, withEvent event: UIEvent?) -> UIView? {
    let uiview = super.hitTest(point, withEvent: event)
    print("hittest",uiview)
    return overlapHitTest(point, withEvent: event)
}
```