# Interaction beyond bounds of UIView

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa, uiview, uibutton

Is it possible for a UIButton (or any other control for that matter) to receive touch events when the UIButton's frame lies outside of it's parent's frame? Cause when I try this, my UIButton doesn't seem to be able to receive any events. How do I work around this?

Comment: This works perfectly for me. https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/qa/qa2013/qa1812.html Best

Comment: This is also good and relevant (or perhaps a dupe): http://stackoverflow.com/a/31420820/8047

Answer (score 97, accepted):

Yes. You can override the `hitTest:withEvent:` method to return a view for a larger set of points than that view contains. See the [UIView Class Reference](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiview).

**Edit:** Example:

```
- (UIView *)hitTest:(CGPoint)point withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    CGFloat radius = 100.0;
    CGRect frame = CGRectMake(-radius, -radius,
                              self.frame.size.width + radius,
                              self.frame.size.height + radius);

    if (CGRectContainsPoint(frame, point)) {
        return self;
    }
    return nil;
}
```

**Edit 2:** (After clarification:) In order to ensure that the button is treated as being within the parent's bounds, you need to override `pointInside:withEvent:` in the parent to include the button's frame.

```
- (BOOL)pointInside:(CGPoint)point withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    if (CGRectContainsPoint(self.view.bounds, point) ||
        CGRectContainsPoint(button.view.frame, point))
    {
        return YES;
    }
    return NO;
}
```

**Note** the code just there for overriding pointInside is not quite correct. As Summon explains below, do this:

```
-(BOOL)pointInside:(CGPoint)point withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
    {
    if ( CGRectContainsPoint(self.oversizeButton.frame, point) )
        return YES;

    return [super pointInside:point withEvent:event];
    }
```

Note that you'd very likely do it with `self.oversizeButton` as an IBOutlet in this UIView subclass; then you can just drag the "oversize button" in question, to, the special view in question. (Or, if for some reason you were doing this a lot in a project, you'd have a special UIButton subclass, and you could look through your subview list for those classes.) Hope it helps.

Comment: Can you help me further on implementing this correctly with some sample code? Also I read the reference and because of the following line, I'm confused: "Points that lie outside the receiver’s bounds are never reported as hits, even if they actually lie within one of the receiver’s subviews. Subviews may extend visually beyond the bounds of their parent if the parent view’s clipsToBounds property is set to NO. However, hit testing always ignores points outside of the parent view’s bounds."

Comment: It's especially this part that makes it seem as if this is not the solution I need: "However, hit testing always ignores points outside of the parent view’s bounds".. But I could be wrong ofcourse, I find the apple references sometimes really confusing..

Comment: Ah, I understand now. You need to override the parent's `pointInside:withEvent:` to include the frame of the button. I will add some sample code to my answer above.

Comment: Is there a way of doing this without overriding methods of a UIView?  For instance, if your views are entirely generic to UIKit and initialized via a Nib, can you override these methods from within your UIViewController?

Comment: You can't override the methods directly; however, you could override `touchesBegan` etc. as `UIViewController` is a `UIResponder` subclass. Views initialized directly from nibs can still be custom subclasses. Just set the Class field of your view in the Identity Inspector to be your custom subclass and, after loading, cast your nib accordingly.

Comment: One other note about this solution.  In hitTest:withEvent: you should return the lowest descendant that matches the hit test.  What this means is that if you have a button outside the bounds of the parent view, you would hitTest that button first and return it, then just call 'return [super hitTest:point withEvent:event];'

Comment: Shouldn't the frame tested in the first block be CGRectMake(-radius, -radius, self.frame.size.width + 2 * radius, self.frame.size.height + 2 * radius)? Otherwise the overflow on the right and bottom edge is flush with the original right and bottom.

Comment: The method is not called.

Comment: Thanks, this put me in the right way to go. i override pointInside of my button parent view to return true (on custom frame size) and that made all the work.

Comment: `hitTest:withEvent:` and `pointInside:withEvent:` area not called for me when I press on a button that lies outside of parent's bounds. What can be wrong?

Answer (score 24):

@jnic, I am working on iOS SDK 5.0 and in order to get your code working right I had to do this:

```
- (BOOL)pointInside:(CGPoint)point withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
if (CGRectContainsPoint(button.frame, point)) {
    return YES;
}
return [super pointInside:point withEvent:event]; }
```

The container view in my case is a UIButton and all the child elements are also UIButtons that can move outside the bounds of the parent UIButton.

Best

Answer (score 23):

In my case, I had a `UICollectionViewCell` subclass that contained a `UIButton`. I disabled `clipsToBounds` on the cell and the button was visible outside of the cell's bounds. However, the button was not receiving touch events. I was able to detect the touch events on the button by using Jack's answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/30431157/3344977

Here's a Swift version:

```
override func hitTest(point: CGPoint, withEvent event: UIEvent?) -> UIView? {

    let translatedPoint = button.convertPoint(point, fromView: self)

    if (CGRectContainsPoint(button.bounds, translatedPoint)) {
        print("Your button was pressed")
        return button.hitTest(translatedPoint, withEvent: event)
    }
    return super.hitTest(point, withEvent: event)
}
```

Swift 4:

```
override func hitTest(_ point: CGPoint, with event: UIEvent?) -> UIView? {

    let translatedPoint = button.convert(point, from: self)

    if (button.bounds.contains(translatedPoint)) {
        print("Your button was pressed")
        return button.hitTest(translatedPoint, with: event)
    }
    return super.hitTest(point, with: event)
}
```

Comment: That was exactly my scenario . The other point is you should put this method inside the CollectionViewCell Class .

Comment: But why would you inject the button to an overridden method???

Answer (score 22):

In the parent view you can override the hit test method:

```
- (UIView *)hitTest:(CGPoint)point withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    CGPoint translatedPoint = [_myButton convertPoint:point fromView:self];

    if (CGRectContainsPoint(_myButton.bounds, translatedPoint)) {
        return [_myButton hitTest:translatedPoint withEvent:event];
    }
    return [super hitTest:point withEvent:event];

}
```

In this case, if the point falls within the bounds of your button, you forward the call there; if not, revert to the original implementation.

Answer (score 11):

**Why this is happening?**

This is because when your subview lies outside of your superview's bounds, touch events that actually happens on that subview will not be delivered to that subview. However, it **WILL** be delivered to its superview.

> Regardless of whether or not subviews are clipped visually, touch events always respect the bounds rectangle of the target view’s superview. In other words, touch events occurring in a part of a view that lies outside of its superview’s bounds rectangle are not delivered to that view. [Link](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/WindowsViews/Conceptual/ViewPG_iPhoneOS/WindowsandViews/WindowsandViews.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009503-CH2-SW10)

**What you need to do?**

When your superview receives the touch event mentioned above, you'll need to tell  UIKit explicitly that my subview should be the one to receive this touch event.

**What about the code?**

In your superview, implement `func hitTest(_ point: CGPoint, with event: UIEvent?)`

```
override func hitTest(_ point: CGPoint, with event: UIEvent?) -> UIView? {
        if isHidden || alpha == 0 || clipsToBounds { return super.hitTest(point, with: event) }
        // convert the point into subview's coordinate system
        let subviewPoint = self.convert(point, to: subview)
        // if the converted point lies in subview's bound, tell UIKit that subview should be the one that receives this event
        if !subview.isHidden && subview.bounds.contains(subviewPoint) { return subview }
        return super.hitTest(point, with: event)
    }
```

**Fascinating gotchya: you must go to the "highest too-small superview"**

You have to go "up" to the "highest" view which the problem view is outside.

Typical example:

Say you have a screen S, with a container view C.  The container viewcontroller's view is V. (Recall V will sit inside of C and be the identical size.) V has a subview (maybe a button) B.  B is the problem view which is actually outside of V.

*But note that B is also outside of C.*

In this example you have to apply the solution `override hitTest` in fact **to C, not to V**.  If you apply it to V - it does nothing.

Comment: Thank you for this!  I have spent hours and hours on an issue stemming from this.  I really appreciate your taking the time to post this.  :)

Comment: @ScottZhu :  I did add an important gotchya to your answer.  Of course, you should feel free to delete or change my addition!  Thanks again!

Answer (score 9):

Swift:

Where targetView is the view you wish to receive the event (which may be entirely or partially located outside of the frame of its parent view).

```
override func hitTest(point: CGPoint, withEvent event: UIEvent?) -> UIView? {
        let pointForTargetView: CGPoint = targetView.convertPoint(point, fromView: self)
        if CGRectContainsPoint(targetView.bounds, pointForTargetView) {
            return closeButton
        }
        return super.hitTest(point, withEvent: event)
}
```

Answer (score 7):

For me (as for others), the answer was **not** to override the `hitTest` method, but rather the `pointInside` method. I had to do this in only two places.

**The Superview**
This is the view that if it had `clipsToBounds` set to true, it would make this whole problem disappear. So here's my simple `UIView` in Swift 3:

```
class PromiscuousView : UIView {
    override func point(inside point: CGPoint,
               with event: UIEvent?) -> Bool {
        return true
    }
}
```

**The Subview**
Your mileage may vary, but in my case I also had to overwrite the `pointInside` method for the subview that was had decided the touch was out of bounds. Mine is in Objective-C, so:

```
- (BOOL)pointInside:(CGPoint)point withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    WEPopoverController *controller = (id) self.delegate;
    if (self.takeHitsOutside) {
        return YES;
    } else {
        return [super pointInside:point withEvent:event];
    }
}
```

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4961484/8047) (and a few others on the same question) can help clear up your understanding.

Answer (score 2):

swift 4.1 updated

To get touch events in same UIView you just need to add following override method, it will identify specific view tapped in UIView which is placed out of bound

```
override func hitTest(_ point: CGPoint, with event: UIEvent?) -> UIView? {
    let pointforTargetview:CGPoint = self.convert(point, to: btnAngle)
    if  btnAngle.bounds.contains(pointforTargetview) {
        return  self
    }
    return super.hitTest(point, with: event)
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I know this is very old question but still we need these solutions as updated version that's why I'll share new version solution of this problem.

Let's think my `mainView` frame is `CGRect(0.0, 0.0, 250, 250.0)` and I want to add a button sized width & height 50 at as `subView` of my `mainView` (to topLeft corner), it's frame will look like `CGRect(-50, -50, 50, 50)` in `mainView`in this case we cannot interact with this button and here is an example for how to solve this problem

**In your MainView (button container view)** override `hitTest`function as mentioned in other answers but here reverse subviews order and convert hit point to this subview point then only check the result with `hitTest` again else check if your view contains that point return your `mainView` else return nil to avoid affecting other views

```
override func hitTest(_ point: CGPoint, with event: UIEvent?) -> UIView? {
    guard !clipsToBounds && !isHidden && alpha > 0 else { return self.superview }
    for member in subviews.reversed() {
        let subPoint = member.convert(point, from: self)
        guard let result = member.hitTest(subPoint, with: event) else { continue }
        return result
    }
    return self.bounds.contains(point) ? self : nil
}
```

I have tested and used this code in my own app and it works well.

Answer (score 0):

Swift 5 version of the first part of [jnic's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5433189/3151675):

```
override func hitTest(_ point: CGPoint, with event: UIEvent?) -> UIView? {
    let radius: CGFloat = 100

    let frame = CGRect(
        x: -radius,
        y: -radius,
        width: frame.width + radius * 2,
        height: frame.height + radius * 2
    )

    if frame.contains(point) {
        return self
    }
    
    return nil
}
```