# Control UIScrollView outside bounds?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uiscrollview, bounds

I'm wondering how i can allow the user to scroll outside the bounds of a UIScrollView?

Comment: I don't understand what you mean.

Comment: The user can scroll my uiscrollview as they would usually, but i want to make it so when they drag outside of the bounds of the uiscrollview, it still scrolls the uiscrollview.

Comment: Doesn't UIScrollView do that by default?

Comment: When they start the drag outside the uiscrollview, i want the uiscrollview to scroll.

Comment: Ohhh I see. That's definitely trickier. You can try forwarding touch events from the various UIView methods of the superview to the scrollview, and see if that will work.  Or you might try using a `UIPanGestureRecognizer` on the superview and explicitly set the scroll view offset when you get the pan events.

Comment: @Daniel Dickison: Your comment is a good answer. You can write it as an answer and i would like to upvote it for the solution you have given.

Comment: done, and added some rough examples.

Comment: Take a look at [UIScrollView horizontal paging like Mobile Safari tabs][1], this is where i found a solution to your question.


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1220354/uiscrollview-horizontal-paging-like-mobile-safari-tabs

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can try forwarding touch events from the various UIView methods of the superview to the scrollview, and see if that will work. E.g:

```
- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    [scrollView touchesBegan:touches withEvent:event];
}
// etc
```

Or you might try using a UIPanGestureRecognizer on the superview and explicitly set the scroll view offset when you get the pan events. E.g:

```
- (void)handlePan:(UIPanGestureRecognizer *)pan
{
    scrollView.contentOffset = [pan translationInView:scrollView];
}
// Or something like that.
```

Comment: It can be tough to get the scrolling animation right when you "throw" the scrollview. That is, when `[pan velocityInView:pan.view]` is nonzero.

Answer (score 6):

Try subclassing the `UIScrollView` and overriding `hitTest:withEvent:` so that the `UIScrollView` picks up touches outside its bounds. Something like this:

```
@interface MagicScrollView : UIScrollView
@end

@implementation MagicScrollView

- (UIView *)hitTest:(CGPoint)point withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    // Intercept touches 100pt outside this view's bounds on all sides
    if (CGRectContainsPoint(CGRectInset(self.bounds, -100, -100), point)) {
        return self;
    }
    return nil;
}

@end
```

You may also need to override `pointInside:withEvent:` on the `UIScrollView`'s superview, depending on your layout.

See the following question for more info: [interaction beyond bounds of uiview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5432995/interaction-beyond-bounds-of-uiview)