# How to make possible interaction with child UIView's drawn outside the parent UIView bounds?

Tags: ios, uiview, parent

I have something like a mixer, which opens the tracks volumes when I touch a button.

To avoid making the view bigger than it needs, i'm drawing the volume sliders outside the bounds. The thing is that now, I have the touch being handled by what is below those sliders and not the sliders them selfs.

How can I make a UIView child receive the touch when it is outside the parents bound, but above anything else that is drawn around?

Is this possible?

I tried the hit test method suggested in the link below without success:

[interaction beyond bounds of uiview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5432995/interaction-beyond-bounds-of-uiview)

Thanks,

With my best regards,

Nuno Santos

Answer (score 1):

I have found the solution to this problem. Basically I need to override the method

```
-(BOOL)pointInside:(CGPoint)point withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
```

which

"Returns a Boolean value indicating whether the receiver contains the specified point."

First I test the point with the super view. If it returns none, I'll test against the objects that are being drawn outside the parent's bounds.

```
-(BOOL)pointInside:(CGPoint)point withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    if ([super pointInside:point withEvent:event])
    {
        return YES;
    }
    else
    {
        id elem;

        NSEnumerator * enumerator = [tracks objectEnumerator];

        while(elem = [enumerator nextObject])
        {
            LKTrack *track = (LKTrack*) elem;

            if ([track pointInside:[self convertPoint:point toView:track] withEvent:event])
            {
                return YES;
            }
        }
    }

    return NO;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

In the answer above, what is the 'tracks' and how do you get it?

Comment: This is not an answer. You should delete this and post a comment under the answer in question.