# UIButton is not clickable

Tags: ios, objective-c, uibutton

I have a function where I move the main view to the side to expose a `UIButton`. The part of the button that's inside the view is clickable but the right side of the button is not.
I've changed the self.view.frame to a much bigger number but I'm still facing the same problem. I've also tried playing around with `insertSubview:aboveSubview:` but that also didn't helped.

```
self.view.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 1600, 568);
_testView = [[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(300, 20, 120, 100)];
_testView.backgroundColor = [UIColor greenColor];

UIButton *test = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
test.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 120, 100);
[test addTarget:self action:@selector(doSomething) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

[_testView addSubview:test];
[self.view addSubview:_testView];

- (void)showRightMenu
{
    CGRect frame = self.view.frame;
    frame.origin.x = -100;
self.view.frame = frame
}
```

**Edit:** I've uploaded a sample project of my problem https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/137356839/TestMePlz.zip

Comment: Have you tried setting clipsToBounds = NO; on your _testView?

Comment: Touch works on the visible touchable area, not on the bigger view, not matter how big is your view, you cannot touch beyond 320 in case of portrait mode, however in landscape mode you can touch upto 480 only..

Comment: @Mikael Yes. The button is visible just not clickable at his right part.

Comment: Have you tried bringing it to the front? [self.view bringSubviewToFront:test];

Comment: @mashdup Yes, that's not the problem.

Comment: Do a stupid test. Set different background colors on all your views so you can see how it looks. Might be worth it.

Comment: oh, and check the bounds of the button and it's superview.

Comment: How can I check its superview?

Comment: @Sha, I mean in this case it's the _testView that is the superview. Sorry for not being clear...

Comment: NSLog(@"%@", NSStringFromCGRect(test.bounds)); gives me `{{0, 0}, {120, 100}}`

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/32665/discussion-between-mikael-and-sha)

Comment: I've edited my question with a sample project of my problem.

Answer (score 2):

After you sent me your code I changed some things:

First I created a container view (makes it easier to track all the views):

```
_contatinerView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.frame];
```

So all the views you put in `self.view` I moved to `_containerView`. Then I obviously added the `_containerView` to `self.view`.

Instead of using:

```
CGRect frame = self.view.frame;
frame.origin.x = -100;
self.view.frame = frame;
```

I did:

```
[_contatinerView setTransform:CGAffineTransformTranslate(_contatinerView.transform,-100, 0)];
```

You'll have to add the QuartzCore and CoreGraphics frameworks.

Comment: Yes, didn't you get the link? Here it is: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/768979/TestMePlz.zip

Comment: The problem is that if for example I'll drag a UISlider or a button to the ViewController in the interface builder, when clicking on the rightMenuButton I will see the menu but the main viewController won't move to the left. So, it shows me the right menu but doesn't move the current ViewController to the side.

Comment: But if you remove all references to _containerView and change it to self.view (as you had before) you can add stuff in IB and it will be moved with it.

Comment: You're right. The current ViewController will move But then the button in the right menu is not clickable again.. back to square one.

Comment: Don't have much time to spend on this right now. But have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5432995/interaction-beyond-bounds-of-uiview . Seems to solve the issue.

Comment: Looks like the right solution but for some reason `pointInside:withEvent` is not getting called. I'd love to see how you implement this when you'll have more time. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Please correct position of your View :

```
self.view.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 568);
_testView = [[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 20, 320, 100)];
_testView.backgroundColor = [UIColor greenColor];

UIButton *test = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
test.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 120, 100);
[test addTarget:self action:@selector(doSomething) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

[_testView addSubview:test];
[self.view addSubview:_testView];
```

Thanks.

Comment: @Sha you are not able to click on the half part of UIButton due to testview frame. its start from 300.0 and ands at 320.0.

Comment: How can I fix this? I tried editing the testView frame without success. I've uploaded a sample project to my question.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
[test addTarget:self action:@selector(doSomething:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

And then change your method:

```
-(void)doSomething:(id)sender
{
    NSLog(@"Bug Fixes:!!!!!!!");
}
```

I did it in your project and button works.