# Swift - UIButton created programatically doesn't trigger touch event

Tags: ios, swift, events, uibutton

I have created a button programatically and want to add a touch event handler. I have tried all the tricks I have found online but the desired function is just never triggered.

```
upgradeNowView = UIButton()
upgradeNowView.setTitle("Upgrade", forState: .Normal)
upgradeNowView.contentMode = UIViewContentMode.ScaleToFill
upgradeNowView.frame = CGRect(x: upgradeNowView.frame.minX, y: -50 , width: 320, height: 50)
upgradeNowView.userInteractionEnabled = true
upgradeNowView.sendActionsForControlEvents(.TouchUpInside)
upgradeNowView.addTarget(self, action: #selector(MainViewContainer.upgradeTapped(_:)), forControlEvents: .TouchUpInside)
side_menu_controller?.view.addSubview(upgradeNowView)
```

and defined this

```
func upgradeTapped(sender: UIButton)
{
    UpgradeViewController.openUpgrade()
}
```

But this just never gets called. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: your selector is on `MainViewContainer` and button is in `side_menu_controller`

Answer (score 0):

You need to define `upgradeTapped` function in class of `side_menu_controller` instance. I guess, it's `SideMenuController` class.

Answer (score 0):

I found out this was caused by the fact that I was placing the button next to the view but outside its bounds (just on top):

```
upgradeNowView.frame = CGRect(x: upgradeNowView.frame.minX, y: -50 , width: 320, height: 50)
```

There are two ways around this:

- Move the button inside the bounds of the parent view, or
- Handle touches outside the view by overriding "hitTest" as discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5432995/interaction-beyond-bounds-of-uiview)