# UIView containing UITableView extends outside bounds of Parent UIView and does not scroll

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uiview

I have a custom `UIView` and `.xib` called `ViewA`, `ViewA` has a fixed height of `60pts`. `ViewA` has a subview named `ViewB` (which has its own `.xib`) which contains a `UITableView`. `ViewB` is initially hidden and has a height of `400pts` (much bigger than the height of `ViewA`). `ViewA` also has button which shows and hides `ViewB`. `ViewB`s `X` and `Y` coordinates are `0,0` to that of `ViewA`, `ViewB` also has the same width as `ViewA`. When pressing `ViewA`s button to reveal `ViewB` it is shown correctly - `ViewB` extends outside of `ViewA`s bounds. However, I can only scroll `ViewB`s `UITableView` within the first `60pts` (the bounds of `ViewA`) the rest of the extended view does not scroll.

I have tried using `hitTest` answers found here but I cannot seem to get it to work.

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/29869695/2654425

The desired effect is that `ViewA` will display `ViewB` which should have its full interaction and act as normal. `ViewB` should also overlap any other views that may be in a `UIViewController`. It works fine apart from the UITableView in `ViewB` not being fully scrollable ie. scrolling from the row at `index 0` scrolls the table fine, but there is no scrolling from `index 5`` for example.

Any help would be greatly appreciated?

Some more info:

- Autolayout is being used in the storyboard
- `ViewB`s `zPosition` is 1
- the desired effect is similar to date of a DropDown menu.
- I dont want to use a third party library

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Set .clipsToBounds = true` on ViewA and you'll see why you can't scroll. You need to change the height of ViewA to match the height of ViewB.

Comment: @DonMag ya I did that thanks. I tried adjusting the height also, when ViewB is being presented I set ViewA to have the same height as it. ViewB was still unscrollabe. But when I dismissed ViewB, ViewA was the new height that I set. However I did notice that the button I was using to reveal ViewB was only clickable within its original height also, not the new one 

Comment: Hmmm... still sounds like a bounds issue. Is ViewA *also* contained in another, shorter view?

Comment: @DonMag ViewA is just in a ViewController. It’s possible that’s something else is going on with my .xib maybe

Comment: To debug... set all related views to `Clip to Bounds`, and give each one a different background color. That often makes it much easier to see what's going on at run-time. Also, use Debug View Hierarchy to check the views.