# Understanding NSRunLoop

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, nsrunloop

Can anyone explain for what is `NSRunLoop`? so as I know `NSRunLoop` is a something connected with `NSThread` right? So assume I create a Thread like

```
NSThread* th=[[NSThread alloc] initWithTarget:self selector:@selector(someMethod) object:nil];
[th start];

-(void) someMethod
{
    NSLog(@"operation");
}
```

so after this Thread finishes his working right? why use `RunLoops` or where to use ?  from Apple docs I have read something but its not clear for me, so please explain as simple as it possible

Comment: This question is too broad in scope.  Please refine your question to something more specific.

Comment: at first i want to know what do in genereal NSRunLoop and how it connected with Thread

Comment: a blog to deeply understand NSRunloop in iOS https://suelan.github.io/2021/02/13/20210213-dive-into-runloop-ios/

Answer (score 226, accepted):

A run loop is an abstraction that (among other things) provides a mechanism to handle system input sources (sockets, ports, files, keyboard, mouse, timers, etc).

Each NSThread has its own run loop, which can be accessed via the currentRunLoop method.

In general, you do not need to access the run loop directly, though there are some (networking) components that may allow you to specify which run loop they will use for I/O processing.

A run loop for a given thread will wait until one or more of its input sources has some data or event, then fire the appropriate input handler(s) to process each input source that is "ready.".

After doing so, it will then return to its loop, processing input from various sources, and "sleeping" if there is no work to do.

That's a pretty high level description (trying to avoid too many details).

**EDIT**

An attempt to address the comment.  I broke it into pieces.

> - it means that i can only access/run to run loop inside the thread
>     right?

Indeed.  NSRunLoop is not thread safe, and should only be accessed from the context of the thread that is running the loop.

> - is there any simple example how to add event to run loop?

If you want to monitor a port, you would just add that port to the run loop, and then the run loop would watch that port for activity.

```
- (void)addPort:(NSPort *)aPort forMode:(NSString *)mode
```

You can also add a timer explicitly with

```
- (void)addTimer:(NSTimer *)aTimer forMode:(NSString *)mode
```

> - what means it will then return to its loop?

The run loop will process all ready events each iteration (according to its mode).  You will need to look at the documentation to discover about run modes, as that's a bit beyond the scope of a general answer.

> - is run loop inactive when i start the thread?

In most applications, the main run loop will run automatically.  However, you are responsible for starting the run loop and responding to incoming events for threads you spin.

> - is it possible to add some events to Thread run loop outside the thread?

I am not sure what you mean here.  You don't add events to the run loop.  You add input sources and timer sources (from the thread that owns the run loop).  The run loop then watches them for activity.  You can, of course, provide data input from other threads and processes, but input will be processed by the run loop that is monitoring those sources on the thread that is running the run loop.

> - does it mean that sometimes i can use run loop to block thread for a time

Indeed.  In fact, a run loop will "stay" in an event handler until that event handler has returned.  You can see this in any app simply enough.  Install a handler for any IO action (e.g., button press) that sleeps.  You will block the main run loop (and the whole UI) until that method completes.

The same applies to any run loop.

I suggest you read the following documentation on run loops:

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsrunloop

and how they are used within threads:

https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Multithreading/RunLoopManagement/RunLoopManagement.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000057i-CH16-SW1

Comment: it means that i can only access/run to run loop inside the thread right? is there any simple example how to add event to run loop ? what means  it will then return to its loop? is run loop inactive when i start the thread? is it possible to add some events to Thread run loop outside the thread? does it mean that sometimes i can use run loop to block thread for a time ?

Comment: "Install a handler for any IO action (e.g., button press) that sleeps." Do you mean if I continue to hold my finger on the button, it will continue to block the thread for a time?!

Comment: No.  What I mean is that the runloop does not process new events until the handler has completed.  If you sleep (or do some operation that takes a long time) in the handler, then the run loop will block until the handler has completed its work.

Comment: @taffarel *is it possible to add some events to Thread run loop outside the thread?* If that means "can I make code run on the runloop of another thread at will" then the answer is indeed yes. Just call `performSelector:onThread:withObject:waitUntilDone:`, passing a `NSThread` object and your selector will be scheduled on the runloop of that thread.

Answer (score 16):

> Run loops are what *separates* **interactive** apps from
>   **command-line** tools.
>
> - Command-line tools are launched with parameters, execute their command, then exit.
> - Interactive apps **wait** for user input, react, then resume waiting.
>
> <sub>From [here](http://bou.io/RunRunLoopRun.html)</sub>

They allow you to wait till user taps and respond accordingly, wait till you get a completionHandler and apply its results, wait till you get a timer and perform a function. If you don't have a runloop then you can't be listening/waiting for user taps, you can't wait till a network call is happening, you can't be awoken in x minutes unless you use `DispatchSourceTimer` or `DispatchWorkItem`

Also from [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45463996/how-does-urlsessiontask-run/45464390#comment77989568_45464390):

> Background threads don't have their own runloops, but you can just add
>   one. E.g. [AFNetworking 2.x](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking/blob/2.x/AFNetworking/AFURLConnectionOperation.m#L157) did it. It was tried and true technique for
>   NSURLConnection or NSTimer on background threads, but we don't do this
>   ourselves much anymore, as newer APIs eliminate the need to do so. But
>   it appears that URLSession does, e.g., [here is simple request](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zuEJi.png), running [see the left panel of the image]
>   completion handlers on the main queue, and you can see it has a run
>   loop on background thread

---

Specifically about: "Background threads don't have their own runloops". The following timer fails to fire for an **async** dispatch:

```
class T {
    var timer: Timer?

    func fireWithoutAnyQueue() {
        timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 1, repeats: false, block: { _ in
            print("without any queue") // success. It's being ran on main thread, since playgrounds begin running from main thread
        })
    }

    func fireFromQueueAsnyc() {
        let queue = DispatchQueue(label: "whatever")
        queue.async {
            self.timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 1, repeats: false, block: { (_) in
                print("from a queue — async") // failed to print
            })
        }
    }

    func fireFromQueueSnyc() {
        let queue = DispatchQueue(label: "whatever")
        queue.sync {
            timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 1, repeats: false, block: { (_) in
                print("from a queue — sync") // success. Weird. Read my possible explanation below
            })
        }
    }

    func fireFromMain() {
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self.timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 1, repeats: false, block: { (_) in
                print("from main queue — sync") //success
            })
        }
    }
}
```

I think the reason the `sync` block also runs is because:

*sync* blocks usually just get executed from within their *source* queue. In this example, source queue is main queue, the *whatever* queue is the destination queue.

To test that I logged `RunLoop.current` inside every dispatch.

The sync dispatch had the **same** runloop as main queue. While the RunLoop within the async block was a different instance from the others. You might be thinking how why does `RunLoop.current` return a different value. Isn't it a *shared* value!? Great question! Read further:

**IMPORTANT NOTE:**

The **class property** [`current`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/runloop/1412291-current) is NOT a global variable.

> Returns the run loop for the **current** thread.

It's contextual. It's visible only within the scope of the thread ie [Thread-local storage](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thread-local_storage). For more on that see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35692188/what-is-thread-local-storage-why-we-need-it).

This is a known issue with timers. You don't have the same issue if you use `DispatchSourceTimer`

Answer (score 8):

**RunLoops are a bit of like a box where stuff just happens.**

Basically, in a RunLoop, you go to process some events and then return. Or return if it doesn't process any events before the timeout is hit. 
You can say it as similar to asynchronous NSURLConnections, Processing data in the background without interfering your current loop and but at the same time, you require data synchronously.
Which can be done with the help of RunLoop which makes your asynchronous `NSURLConnection` and provides data at calling time.
You can use a RunLoop like this:

```
NSDate *loopUntil = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:0.1];

while (YourBoolFlag && [[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] runMode: NSDefaultRunLoopMode beforeDate:loopUntil]) {
    loopUntil = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:0.1];
}
```

In this RunLoop, it will run until you complete some of your other work and set **YourBoolFlag** to **false**.

**Similarly, you can use them in threads.**

Hope this helps you.

Answer (score 3):

**iOS RunLoop**

`RunLoop(EventLoop, Looper)` is an implementation of [EventLoop](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Event_loop) (event processing loop) pattern. It is based on `NSRunLoop` (which a wrapper of `CFRunLoopRef`)

[Official doc](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Multithreading/RunLoopManagement/RunLoopManagement.html)

> Run loops are part of the fundamental infrastructure associated with threads. A run loop is an event processing loop that you use to schedule work and coordinate the receipt of incoming events. The purpose of a run loop is to keep your thread busy when there is work to do and put your thread to sleep when there is none.

Single **thread** can have single **RunLoop** in a single **mode**. Only events with this mode will be processed all others will be waiting when RunLoop will be started at that mode

RunLoop is a mechanism (based on loop(for, while)) which move a scheduled task(e.g Callback Queue) to a thread(thread stack). RunLoop works(`event processing loop`) when Thread Stack is empty.

`event processing loop` is when RunLoop between `.entry` and `.exit`. During it RunLoop handles all scheduled task in specific mode. All others modes with their own Queues will be managed after

Application by default has a `main thread` with `RunLoop(main loop)`. In other cases you should create it manually

`main run loop` is responsible for draining the `main queue` in an app.

```
//Run loop for the current thread
RunLoop.current

//Run loop of the main thread.
RunLoop.main
```

[image]

**Mode**

> A run loop mode is a collection of input sources and timers to be monitored and a collection of run loop observers to be notified.

modes:

- default - used by default
- tracking - for example when you scroll UITableView `scrollViewDidScroll`
- common(is a pseudo mode like [default, tracking])
- `<custom>` - you are able to create your own mode

```
//current input mode
RunLoop.current.currentMode
```

For example:

- `UIView.draw(_ rect:)`, button action... uses `default mode`
- [NSObject.perform(_:with:afterDelay:)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/objectivec/nsobject/1416176-perform) uses `default mode`
- `DispatchQueue.main.async` uses `common mode`
- `Timer.scheduledTimer` uses `default mode`. That is why when UI scrolling occurring(`scrollViewDidScroll` where tracking mode is used) your timer is not fired(in default mode). To fix it use common mode - `RunLoop.main.add(timer, forMode: .common)`
- Combine `RunLoop.main` vs `DispatchQueue.main`(`.receive(on:, options:)`). RunLoop.main uses `RunLoop.perform(_:)` which uses `default mode`, DispatchQueue.main uses `DispatchQueue.main.async` which uses `common mode`

**input sources and timers**

Run loop receives events:

- `Input sources` - asynchronous events(as fired) messages

  - Port-based - from another thread or process. signaled automatically by the kernel
  - Custom Input Sources - user-initiated events - user actions, network events. must be signaled manually from another thread
  - `performSelector: onThread`
- `Timer sources` - synchronous events(at specific time) timers

They can be added to **several modes**

**observers**

monitor RunLoop's state changes

**Create RunLoop**

create new thread, setup RunLoop and start the thread

1. create RunLoop
   RunLoop.current
2. A run loop must have at least one input source or timer to monitor
   RunLoop.add(_ timer: Timer, forMode mode: RunLoop.Mode)
   RunLoop.add(_ aPort: Port, forMode mode: RunLoop.Mode)
3. run RunLoop
   RunLoop.run()

```
let thread = Thread {
    //1. create RunLoop
    //create a new one or return existing run loop for current thread
    //use RunLoop.current instead of RunLoop()
    let customRunLoop = RunLoop.current
    
    //add observer for current RunLoop for cpecufic mode
    CFRunLoopAddObserver(CFRunLoopGetCurrent(), customObserver, CFRunLoopMode.commonModes)

    //2. A run loop must have at least one input source or timer to monitor
    let timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 2, repeats: false) { (timer) in
        //.default mode
    }
    customRunLoop.add(timer, forMode: .default)

    //3. run RunLoop
    //If no input sources or timers are attached to the run loop, this method exits immediately
    //infinite loop that processes data from the run loop’s input sources and timers.
    //calls RunLoop.run(mode:.default before:)
    customRunLoop.run()
    
    //------
    
    //create custom mode
    let customRunLoopMode = RunLoop.Mode("customeMode")
    
    //2. A run loop must have at least one input source or timer to monitor
    //Will be called when previous RunLoop.run() is done(no input sources or timers) - exit from loop
    let timer2 = Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 2, repeats: false) { (timer) in
        //"customeMode" mode
    }
    customRunLoop.add(timer2, forMode: customRunLoopMode)
    
    //3. run RunLoop
    let isInputSourcesOrTimers = customRunLoop.run(mode: customRunLoopMode, before: Date.distantFuture)
}

thread.start()


let customObserver = CFRunLoopObserverCreateWithHandler(nil, CFRunLoopActivity.allActivities.rawValue , true, 0) { observer, activity in
    switch (activity) {
    case .entry:
        break
    case .beforeTimers:
        break
    case .beforeSources:
        break
    case .beforeWaiting:
        break
    case .afterWaiting:
        break
    case .exit:
        break
    case .allActivities:
        break
    default:
        break
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> Run loops are part of the fundamental infrastructure associated with threads. A run loop is an event processing loop that you use to schedule work and coordinate the receipt of incoming events. The purpose of a run loop is to keep your thread busy when there is work to do and put your thread to sleep when there is none.

[From here](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Multithreading/RunLoopManagement/RunLoopManagement.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000057i-CH16-SW1)

---

> The most important feature of CFRunLoop is the CFRunLoopModes. CFRunLoop works with a system of “Run Loop Sources”. Sources are registered on a run loop for one or several modes, and the run loop itself is made to run in a given mode. When an event arrives on a source, it is only handled by the run loop if the source mode matches the run loop current mode.

[From here](https://bou.io/RunRunLoopRun.html#fnref:6)

Answer (score 0):

```
Swift
let runLoop = RunLoop.current

Obj-c
NSRunLoop * runloop = [NSRunLoop currentRunLoop];
```

A run loop is an event processing loop that is used to continuously monitor and process input events and assign them to the corresponding targets for processing.