# Is NSRunLoop thread safe?

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, nsrunloop

I am little confused whether `NSRunLoop` is `thread safe or not`. So I need some clarification is it thread safe or not and why?

Any help is appreciable.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There a warning right in the beginning of the `NSRunLoop` [official reference documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/Classes/NSRunLoop_Class/Reference/Reference.html):

> Warning:  The NSRunLoop class is generally **not considered to be thread-safe** and its methods should only be called within the context of the current thread. You should never try to call the methods of an NSRunLoop object running in a different thread, as doing so might cause unexpected results.

Answer (score 1):

`NSRunLoop` is not `thread safe`. See [Apple's Guidelines](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/Classes/NSRunLoop_Class/Reference/Reference.html) for more reference.

Answer (score 0):

No it is not.

Read the documentation from [NSRunLoop Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSRunLoop_Class/Reference/Reference)

> Warning:  The NSRunLoop class is generally not considered to be
>   thread-safe and its methods should only be called within the context
>   of the current thread. You should never try to call the methods of an
>   NSRunLoop object running in a different thread, as doing so might
>   cause unexpected results.

Also check the [NSRunLoop answer on SOF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12091212/understanding-nsrunloop)

Answer (score 0):

Not only is it not thread-safe, it is expressly thread-specific. Each thread that passes messages between `NSObject`s must contain its own `NSRunLoop`. Accessing another thread's runloop can mess up tracked cycles like `-autorelease`d objects, timed events like `NSTimer`s, and sub-runloops setup by things like `-runUntilDate:`. In addition, I'm assuming that `NSRunLoop` will use thread-specific data to store some information. That means you could cause data mismatch between thread-specific data and object stored data.