# What are benefits of NSRunLoop vs dispatch_source_t timer vs ReactiveCocoa bindings

Tags: macos, cocoa, reactive-cocoa, nsrunloop, visual-programming

For learning purpose I'm building a [visual programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visual_programming_language) application on OSX. Basically it is made of one function nodes connected through output -> inputs and forming a graph.

I'm building the connected graph (with CoreData) by using depth-first search, then each node is executed in the graph queue with :

```
NSTimeInterval secondsToFire = 1./250.;

NSString *dispatchName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"info.oz432.timer.queue.%p", self];
dispatch_queue_t queue = dispatch_queue_create([dispatchName UTF8String], 0);

_timer = [self createWithInterval:secondsToFire inQueue:queue usingBlock:^{
    for (NSManagedObject *node in pipeline) {
        [self executeNode:[node objectID] inQueue:queue];
    }
}];
```

With `-createWithInterval:inQueue:usingBlock:`

```
dispatch_source_t timer = dispatch_source_create(DISPATCH_SOURCE_TYPE_TIMER, 0, 0, queue);

if (timer) {

    dispatch_source_set_timer(timer, dispatch_walltime(NULL, 0), interval * NSEC_PER_SEC, interval * NSEC_PER_SEC);
    dispatch_source_set_event_handler(timer, block);
    dispatch_resume(timer);

}

return timer;
```

It's working quite well for now, but I'm wondering:

- if using **ReactiveCocoa** to connect signals from outputs to inputs
  would be a **simplest/more readable/more performant** solution;
- otherwise, why should I choose to run a **NSRunLoop for each of my 'pipelines'**.

I've read a lot about [NSRunLoop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12091212/understanding-nsrunloop), I can see that people involved in ie. GStreamer in Cocoa are managing with NSRunLoop, and that [Vuo](http://vuo.org/) is using it. I guess I understand the basics of it. But I don't understand, and this is my question: **what are the benefits of it** ?