# while loop that checks its condition every second

Tags: ios, swift, while-loop

How does one create a while loop that checks its condition every second?

Maybe something like this:

```
while (isConditionSatisfied){
    // wait for 1 second and than check again
}
```

The system calls this function `bannerViewDidLoadAd` at random times. If it calls it at inappropriate time(condition is unsatisfied-my app is performing some other animation), I would like to defer its implementation(just an UIView animation) until the condition is satisfied(my app has finished animating, now the implementation should be executed). I was thinking I could check the condition in a while loop every second, but as you guys said..this is a bad idea.

Comment: NSTimer would be a good place to start looking https://www.weheartswift.com/nstimer-in-swift/

Comment: What condition are you trying to check? Generally, this is a bad idea, because it keeps your app checking even when nothing has changed. It is much better to listen to an event informing you that something has changed, instead for polling for the change every second, because your user's battery will last longer.

Comment: The answer is to use NSTimer, but as everyone has said **do not do this ... do not do it ever**.

Comment: I explained my question in more detail.

Comment: You could load ad there and ignore untill your conditions are satisfied. but a boolean that you make it false or true depending on wheter you should or not show ad

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Using while loop like this will create an infinite loop actually. You should use Timer().

```
timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 1.0, target: self, selector: #selector(self.loop), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
```

And then

```
@objc
func loop() {
    if yourCondition {
        // your code here
        timer.invalidate()
    }
}
```

Make sure you declare timer with your other variable declarations, so it can be invalidated once your condition has been met:

```
var timer: Timer!
```

Comment: this is the right way, how to do it. just note, that there is no guaranty that the check is running on main thread.

Comment: don't forget to add this: timer.invalidate() once the condition is met!

Comment: do not use `repeat` as a function name, because it's keyword in Swift 4.2

Answer (score 8):

**Swift loop with interval**

iOS 10

```
Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 1, repeats: true) { (timer) in   
    if someCondition {
        timer.invalidate()
    }
}
```

*`withTimeInterval` - number of seconds

[[iOS RunLoop]](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75204210/4770877)

Answer (score 1):

you can do using NSTimer like this one

```
[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1.0 target:self selector:@selector(yourMethodName) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
```

Answer (score 1):

I just put together a Swift NSObject extension that would allow you to do this.  It uses a delay function to allow you to `wait` until certain conditions are met or you cancel it.

https://gist.github.com/d3signerd/795a9dced39cbee056010d5629d9ca06

// Wait Example

```
waitWhile( { [weak self] () -> condition_parameters in

   if let weakSelf = self {
      return ( conditionMet: `criteria to meet`, cancel: false )
   }
   else {
      return ( conditionMet: false, cancel: true )
   }

 }, completion: { [weak self] in

    // Wait completion code goes here...

 })
```

// Delay Example

```
private var cancelableDelayClosure:dispatch_cancelable_closure? = nil

cancelableDelayClosure = delay( 1.0, closure: { () -> () in

    // Delay completion code here...
})

cancelDelay( &cancelableDelayClosure )
```

Answer (score 0):

updated code for swift,

```
let timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(
                timeInterval: 1.0, target: self, selector: #selector(Your_current_vc.yourTask),
                userInfo: nil, repeats: true)


func yourTask() {

}
```