# How can I detect which view is handling my tap?

Tags: ios, uiview, touch-event, uiview-hierarchy

Somewhere towards the bottom of my view hierarchy, I am implementing a touchesBegan method.  It fires on all touches except for single finger taps.  This leads me to believe that somewhere higher up in the hierarchy, a view is intercepting/handling the single finger taps, but I can't find the view for the life of me.  Is there a good way of debugging this?

Comment: Do you think hitTest:withEvent: will be helpful? Look at this thread http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4961386/event-handling-for-ios-how-hittestwithevent-and-pointinsidewithevent-are-r .

Comment: Unfortunately `hitTest:withEvent:` returns the view that is not receiving the tap.  It does not appear to be affected by the gesture recognizer.

Answer (score 0):

Try this way, if it work out:

```
- (void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event 
{
    UITouch *touch = [[event allTouches] anyObject];
    CGPoint touchLocation = [touch locationInView:self.contentView];

    for (UIView *view in self.contentView.subviews)
    {
        if ([view isKindOfClass:[MyCustomView class]] &&
            CGRectContainsPoint(view.frame, touchLocation))
        {

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, `touchesMoved` does not get called either for the tap.  No touch methods are being called on a single-finger tap.  They all work perfectly for multi-finger taps or pans or any other touch other than a single-finger tap.