# How to make irregular shaped UIScrollView?

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uiscrollview

I want to make irregular shaped UIScrollView(using CGPath or UIBezierPath).

The contents will be scrollable and zoomable. And scroll actions will be accepted only in these areas, not rectangular area. Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your could use a CAShapedLayer with a path to create a clipping path and apply this to the Scrollview's layer's mask. Use the same path in the view's `hitTest:withEvent:` to decide, if the UIView should response to a touch or not.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Can you post some links or codes about clipping and hittest?

Comment: hor hit testing: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4961386/event-handling-for-ios-how-hittestwithevent-and-pointinsidewithevent-are-r

Comment: Thanks. Solved using clipping and hittest.