# Moved a toolbar -44 and now the button doesn't work

Tags: iphone, uitoolbar

I made a toolbar over a UIDatePicker and for it to look proper I had to move it up. After I did this the bar item stopped working and was unresponsive.

Working fine :

`UIToolbar *pickerToolbar = [[UIToolbar alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, -29, 320, 22)];`

Not working

`UIToolbar *pickerToolbar = [[UIToolbar alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, -44, 320, 22)];`

It also doesnt work at 30, so 29 must be the stopping point

Answer (score 1):

If the toolbar is a child (subview) of the picker, then it doesn't work because touches aren't registered outside of a view's (the picker) bounds.

You need to either create a common parent view to host both the toolbar and the picker within a single frame, or subclass the picker and do some hitTest: hackery to allow touches from outside the frame.

Comment: would this method work? `[pickerViewDate setBounds:CGRectMake`

Comment: Could you give me some more info on "create a common parent view". And how would I "do some hitTest: hackery to allow touches from outside the frame"

Comment: this question has a good overview:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4961386/event-handling-for-ios-how-hittestwithevent-and-pointinsidewithevent-are-r

Comment: Am I doing something wrong? Because in all other tutorials, they all have it set to (0, 0, 320, 44) and if i do this it is in the middle of my datePicker?

Comment: Im new to programming and would like to stay as simple as possible. The hitTest thing looks way over me and I would like to do the common parent view. Could you give me a link for something on that? I have googled a lot and havn't found anything to do with this question.

Comment: The View Programming Guide is a good place to start:  http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/windowsviews/conceptual/viewpg_iphoneos/CreatingViews/CreatingViews.html