# touches not recognized on tableview when contentOffset set to a negative value

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uiscrollview

I have a table view, and I'm adding a sub view directly to the table view with `addSubview:`. I am displaying this view at the position `CGRectMake(0.0f, -30.0f, tableView.frame.size.width, 30.0f)` (so this displays above the scrollable area of the table, when the user scrolls slightly beyond the bounds of the scroll area). I then do this:

```
- (void) scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView {
    if(scrollView.contentInset.top + scrollView.contentOffset.y < -30.0f) {
        [scrollView setContentOffset:CGPointMake(1.0f, -30.0f)-scrollView.contentInset.top animated:NO];
    }
}
```

So that when a user scrolls up and into the negative space in the table view, that when they release, they can still see the view I insert at y=-30 so that the table does not "snap back" to 0.

This all works exactly like I want it to. However, when the table's `contentOffset` is set to a negative y value such as `[scrollView setContentOffset:CGPointMake(1.0f, -30.0f)-scrollView.contentInset.top animated:NO]`, then touches are NOT recognized on both the cells of my table, nor the view I inserted directly into the table. I am wondering how I can set contentOffset to a value such as this, and still have child views of my tableView, as well as cells, register touches.

Answer (score 1):

It might be easier to just add `30.0f` to `contentInset.top` so that you can continue to use a stock table view.

If you still want use the approach you outlined, you need to override `hitTest:withEvent:` in a `UITableView` subclass:

```
- (UIView *)hitTest:(CGPoint)point withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    if (CGRectContainsPoint(self.theViewInQuestion.frame, point)) {
        return self.theViewInQuestion;
    }

    return [super hitTest:point withEvent:event];
}
```

By default iOS views don't respond to touches outside their bounds, so what the code does is tell the event handling system that you consider `theViewInQuestion` to be inside of the table even though it is above the origin and out of bounds.

"[Event handling for iOS - how hitTest:withEvent: and pointInside:withEvent: are related?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4961386/event-handling-for-ios-how-hittestwithevent-and-pointinsidewithevent-are-r)" has some great answers on how the system works if you want additional detail.