# If I want to make a larger hit area for a UIButton should I override hitTest: or pointInside:?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uibutton

The code is similar for both but what's the "best" way? If I'm reading things right it seems override hitTest: would be faster since it doesn't have to traverse all the child views but putting it in pointInside: seems safer since other methods/classes might call pointInside: to see how large the button is. Is there a winner here or does it not matter?

Answer (score 1):

`hitTest` calls `pointInside` so i would definitely go for the changes in `pointInside`.

Pros and Cons can be found here: [Event handling for iOS - how hitTest:withEvent: and pointInside:withEvent: are related?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4961386/event-handling-for-ios-how-hittestwithevent-and-pointinsidewithevent-are-r)

Comment: That does a good job of explaining how it works but it still doesn't give a solid answer as to which one is better. It seems overriding pointInside: would be less efficient since it's a recursive call where if you just override hitTest: it's one and done. pointInsde: seems more correct but I'm not sure why, every example I see online shows just override hitTest:

Comment: I think there is no perfect answer.