# Embedded UITableView does not detect a swipe to delete row gesture

Tags: swift, uitableview, uiscrollview, uicollectionview, uigesturerecognizer

I have a UITableView embedded inside of a UICollectionView, the collection view scrolls horizontally so if i try a 'swipe to delete' on one of the table view rows which is inside of a collection view cell, it obviously just scrolls the collection view. Was wondering if there is a work around so that it could detect the swipe on the uitableview part of the collection view cell instead of swiping the uicollection view itself? The UITableView only takes up about a quarter of the collection view cell. I'm using a UIViewController. And i also have paging enabled on my collection view.

Comment: This function is special TableViewController function. Which Controller are you using?

Comment: UIViewController, thanks for reminding me about that. I'll edit the question

Comment: Have you included the UITableViewDelegate in the Controller? At the top?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try one of the two options:

- Look at [`require(toFail otherGestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uigesturerecognizer/1624203-require). Add the swipe gestures with this method to the collection view pan gesture when you create (or populate) the cells.
- Try to look at [`shouldRequireFailure(of: otherGestureRecognizer)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uigesturerecognizer/1620006-shouldrequirefailure). Subclass `UICollectionView` and override this method to return true when `otherGestureRecognizer` is actually a swipe to delete row gesture.

You just have to figure how you can identify/retrieve both of the gesture recognizers (hint: browse the [`gestureRecognizers`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiview/1622542-gesturerecognizers) property to find some `PanGestureRecognizers`)

---

And you should definitely refine that clunky design.

Answer (score 1):

You may use as workaround implementing the hit test like described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31420820/2448590) for make that the UICollectionView don't get the gestures events when scrolling inside the cell's frame

but IMHO you should not try to break the default behavior and should look to change your UI...

Answer (score -1):

You can try adding a `UISwipeGestureRecognizer` to each collection cell and then in it's target action check `(gestureRecognizer.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded)` and add your code.