# UIButton with background and increased tabbing arrea

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton, swift4

I would like to have a small rounded UIButton with background. but increased tabbing arrea

[image]

Background is not an image, but a bacground color + layer.cornerRadius.

I have checked inserts, but not sure I can sort it out with background...and I don't wont to increase the size of the app, by using images

[image]

The problem is only with increased tabbing arrea. I know how to set button background and rounded corners. Any advices would be appreciated

Comment: You best option is to use `UIControl` instead of `UIButton` and just put a `UIView` inside it.

Comment: Hi @Sulthan. Thank you for your comment. Could you please provide an example what do you mean, please

Comment: What is a "tabbing area"? — Do you mean _tapping_?

Comment: a neat trick is to design a `UIView` and overlay an empty `UIButton` over your tappable area!

Answer (score 1):

Just override `hitTest` and you'll be fine. You can read more about this on [Apple docs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4961386/event-handling-for-ios-how-hittestwithevent-and-pointinsidewithevent-are-r/4961492#4961492) and [this SO answer](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiview/1622469-hittest).

Answer (score 0):

> Background is not an image, but a bacground color + layer.cornerRadius

Well, that's the problem. You cannot make a button magically "feel" a tap outside its own boundaries. Your button's boundaries are the boundaries of the red rounded rectangle. A tap outside the red rounded rectangle is therefore outside the button.

If you want the tappable area to be bigger, make the *button* bigger. If you then want the red rounded rectangle to be smaller than the button, make it an image.

Comment: _You cannot make a button magically "feel" a tap outside its own boundaries._ Actually, you can. And I'm pretty sure that you've heard (by knowing who you are)  about overriding "-hitTest:" method ;)